# MySQL server crashes, InnoDB outside the tablespace bounds

Tags: mysql, windows, innodb

I have a C# application performing some database operations on a MySQL 5.7 server. Once the complete system hunp up and I had to hard-reset it. When it comes to a specific table read/write operation now the database server crashes. The windows log shows

```
InnoDB: Trying to access page number 286720 in space 29, 
space name myInstance/myTable, which is outside the tablespace bounds.
Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type read.
```

I tried to use `mysqlcheck --repair` but it fails because `note     : The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair`.

I've read some advices that say I should start MySQL in a recovery mode, so I added

```
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery=4
```

to the `my.ini` config file whereupon I should be able to use `mysqldump` to export the affected database table. But unfortunatelly I am not.

```
mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server 
during query when dumping table `myTable` at row: 1246
```

---

**Edit:**

I checked the error log again and found lots of entries saying

```
[ERROR] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: 
The table 'myTable' is full
```

I'm running the server on a Windows 32bit OS with an NTFS formatted partition. The `myTable.ibd` file size is around 4.5 GB, checking [C.10.3 Limits on Table Size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-size-limit.html) states a file size limit of "2TB (possibly larger)" for Win32 w/ NTFS.
While checking the reasons for my error the only possible cause I found was a full InnoDB tablespace. The solution might be "Changing the Number or Size of InnoDB Redo Log Files" although the coherence is a bit vague to me. Nevertheless I increased the size of the Redo Log Files from 48M to 100M. But nothing changed.

If I perform a SQL `select * from myTable order by Id desc` the server crashes instantly. Error log entry is exactly the same as above.

I checked the chapter [15.7.1 Resizing the InnoDB System Tablespace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-resize-system-tablespace.html) as well and found out that `innodb_data_file_path` is not explicitly specified.

Any ideas what I can do now? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sir, I have the exact same problem. Can you tell me how did you resolve the issue, if you ever able to ? I first got 'the table is full' error  and then server crashes on every query event mysqldump. I have tried all recorvery options from 1 to 6.

Comment: Post a bug report at http://bugs/mysql.com

Comment: resolved the issue by switching the whole DBMS. Sorry for the bad news.

Answer (score 2):

InnoDB cannot repair corruption in tablespaces. This was never implemented and `mysqlcheck` won't help in any way.

The corruption is in space id 29 which is table myInstance.myTable. To repair it you need to dump all records from this table with innodb_force_recovery. Try all values from 4 to 6 until MySQL doesn't crash. Then drop the table and reload the dump.

If MySQL crashes even with `innodb_force_recovery=6` then restore the table from backup.

If you don't have backup - use script http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~percona-dev/percona-data-recovery-tool-for-innodb/trunk/view/head:/fetch_data.sh . It will fetch as many records as it can.

Comment: Just to clarify, `innodb_force_recovery` is a server option in the config file.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause could be that the `ib_logfile*` files are corrupted.

To fix this, remove these files using `rm ib_logfile*`.

*Where are these files?*
These files are in mysql `datadir`. The location of `datadir` depends on the OS. Check `my.cnf`, in osx that should be in `/usr/local/etc`.

Comment: this worked for me, i'm using "xampp cp v3.3.0", i deleted ib_logfile0 from the data directory "C:\xampp\mysql\data".